# Value at $D_\max$ from Kolmogorov-Smirnov test in R

Tags: r, distributions, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I am comparing two distributions using the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test [`ks.test()`] in R and would like to know what the numerical value is where $D_\text{max}$ occurs. It's not in the output of `ks.test()` as far as I can see, so I was wondering if anyone had any ideas about how I could find that out. Thanks!

Comment: Have you drawn the q-q plot?

Comment: I have. Can it be extracted from there?

Comment: No (`qqplot` merely returns both arrays in sorted order), but the plot makes the location of `Dmax` visually evident. If you need it numerically, you can obtain it by copying the first page (or so) of code for `ks.test`.

Comment: @whuber I appreciate the suggestion. I'm looking into the code for the ks.test and having a hard time interpreting where this value may be. Thanks for pointing me in this direction though.

Comment: How about simulating Dn for one sample KS test?

Comment: Since I have problems to sort max value from the Dn

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like that? Dmax occurs at the value `max.at`.

```
set.seed(12345)

x <- rnorm(10000, 5, 5)
y <- rnorm(10000, 7, 6.5)

# remove any missings from the data

x <- x[!is.na(x)]
y <- y[!is.na(y)]

ecdf.x <- ecdf(x)
ecdf.y <- ecdf(y)

plot(ecdf.x, xlim=c(min(c(x,y)), max(c(x,y))), verticals=T, cex.lab=1.2, cex.axis=1.3,
     las=1, col="skyblue4", lwd=2, main="")

plot(ecdf.y, verticals=T, add=T, do.points=FALSE, cex.lab=1.2,
     cex.axis=1.3, col="red", lwd=2)

n.x <- length(x)
n.y <- length(y)

n <- n.x * n.y/(n.x + n.y)
w <- c(x, y)

z <- cumsum(ifelse(order(w) <= n.x, 1/n.x, -1/n.y))

max(abs(z)) # Dmax
[1] 0.1664

ks.test(x,y)$statistic # the same
     D 
0.1664

max.at <- sort(w)[which(abs(z) == max(abs(z)))]
[1] 9.082877

# Draw vertical line

abline(v=max.at, lty=2)

lines(abs(z)~sort(w), col="purple", lwd=2)

legend("topleft", legend=c("x", "y", "|Distance|"), col=c("skyblue4", "red", "purple"), lwd=c(2,2,2), bty="n")
```

[image: Dmax visualization]

Comment: Thanks for this piece of code @COOLSerdash. I had to get rid of some duplicates and NA's from my data set to get this to work, but it appears to be working now.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use @COOLSerdash's answer plus environments to make the `ks.test` function output the value directly, like this:

```
ks.test.2 <- function(x, y, ..., alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"), 
    exact = NULL) 
{
e <- new.env()
ks.test.2 <- ks.test
environment(ks.test.2) <- e
e$C_pkstwo <- stats:::C_pkstwo
    e$C_psmirnov2x <- stats:::C_psmirnov2x
e$C_pkolmogorov2x <- stats:::C_pkolmogorov2x
    e$return <- function(x){
    w<-get("w", envir=parent.frame())
    z<-get("z", envir=parent.frame())
    x$max.at <- sort(w)[which(abs(z) == max(abs(z)))]
    return(x)
    }
ks.test.2(x, y, ..., alternative = c("two.sided", "less", "greater"), 
    exact = NULL)
}
```

The function `ks.test.2` should behave exactly like `ks.test` except that now it also returns the desired `max.at` component.

```
set.seed(12345)

x <- rnorm(10000, 5, 5)
y <- rnorm(10000, 7, 6.5)

ks.test.2(x,y)$max.at
# [1] 9.082877
```

This is only for the two-sided alternative, but you could enhance it to deal with the one-sided alternative if desired.